# jQuery retrieval of a tag being a "second" parent ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML structure that looks like:

```
<tr data-audiofilename="TUNAK.mp3">
  <td>TUNAK.mp3</td>
  <td>
    <button class="btn btn-default broadcastAudio">PLAY</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

jQuery

```
 $('.broadcastAudio').on('click', function () {
    // todo improve
    var audioFileName = $(this).parents().closest('tr').data('audiofilename');
    emitPreloadAudio(audioFileName);
  });
```

How can I make this retrieval of `data('audiofilename')` better?

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').data('audiofilename');` ?!  But what you mean by 'better'?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll read more about closest for some reason since a while I've been thinking it only goes up to 1  parent level.